# What is the best way for two-way binding a UI component to an observable to reduce rendering?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

We are building an MVVM application using mobx and react. Currently our best bet is to create viewmodels and UI components similar to this simplified example.

```
// LoginModel.ts
export class LoginModel {
  @observable
  public userName: string;
  
  @observable
  public password: string;
}

// LoginView.tsx
@observer
export class LoginView extends React.Component<LoginViewProps> {

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.model.userName} onChange={e => this.model.userName = e.value} />        
        <input type="password" value={this.model.password} onChange={e => this.model.password= e.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

AFAIK in this implementation the component will entirely re-render when either `userName` or `password` changes.

What I'd like to achieve is to have our own custom `TextInput` component which woudl be responsible for rendering the layout, styling, receiving user input, and also to show validation errors based on model state, etc. I see two options right now.

1. Expose the `value`, `onChange` and for example `error` in the custom component and use it similarly to the example above. This case the issue is the same, each change in a single observable property would AFAIK re-render the entire "form" component. This is due to the fact that I'm not dereferencing the observable in the `TextInput` component but in the `LoginView`.
2. Expose something like `model: any` and `field: string` and use `model[field]` inside. This way I would do the dereferencing inside the `TextInput` and it could work fine, BUT I'd loose some strong typing and universality.

A few notes:

- At first run I intentionally wouldn't like to use libraries like `react-forms`, etc.
- Also, if anyone spots it, I intentionally wouldn't like to use the `Provider` and `@inject` pattern, I like being explicit.

Could anyone give me some ideas and suggestions about such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is awesome form library for mobx that is using very similar technique https://formstate.github.io, you can probably copy this pattern from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use objects instead of plain strings.

```
interface Str{
  value:string
}
```

then you can use `.value` inside your input component.